# scope of markers variable for google maps (gmaps4rails gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

I'm trying to understand javascript, and the way variables are passed around, but I'm not doing too well.  I'm trying to refresh a google map's markers with ajax, but nothing is happening.

I submit a form, which sends some variables to the controller.  Some stuff is processed, and it responds with .js to...

**find.js.erb**

```
$('#collapseTwo ul').html("<%= j render partial: 'events/sidebar', collection: @events %>");

alert(<%= raw @hash.to_json %>);

clearMarkers();


markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @hash.to_json %>, {
  draggable: false
});
```

The render fires fine, so everything is working there, but I can't seem to get a hold of the markers to refresh the map.  That alert shows `[object Object]`, so that's likely correct, but no action on the markers.

I made some modifications to `marker.coffee` in the form of

```
clear: ->
  @getServiceObject().setMap(null)

show: ->
  @getServiceObject().setVisible(true)

hide: ->
  @getServiceObject().setVisible(false)
```

so that `clearMarkers();` works.  It's in another file, where I'm storing some other actions

**events.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  ...
  ...

@clearMarkers = ->
  for marker in Gmaps.store.markers
    marker.clear()
  Gmaps.store.markers = []
```

So... I call the map initially in with...

```
jQuery ->
  handler = Gmaps.build 'Google'
  handler.buildMap { 
    provider: { 
      minZoom: 3
    }, internal: {id: 'map'} }, ->

      markers = handler.addMarkers( $('#map').data('events'), 
        draggable: false
        flat: false
      )

      #moves map to marker clicked + open infowindow
      $(document).on 'click', '#sideBar li', ->
        markers[$(this).data('marker')].panTo()
        markers[$(this).data('marker')].click()
```

That function on the bottom there... the only way I had access to the `markers` array was because it was inside the `handler.buildMap` function.  So, should the `markers` variable be global?  How else can I act on them?

Also, the `handler` variable... that's it seems to me like that should be available everywhere.  I tried manually putting the `@hash` into `.addMarkers()`, but the handler didn't build the markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a store accessible globally.

I suggest the following:

```
Gmaps.store = {}
jQuery ->
  Gmaps.store.handler = Gmaps.build 'Google'
  Gmaps.store.handler.buildMap...
    Gmaps.store.markers = Gmaps.store.handler.addMarkers(...)
```

You can access the variables within your js.erb as well.

Comment: Boom! You're a life saver. That's a great way to save variables, thanks! And I see the whole global function thing with defining a function with `@clearMarkers = ->`.  When I repeat the same search over and over, the marker goes away, and comes back proper, but if I zoom in or out, there are a bunch of markers around where the one should be... like copies of it.  Does my `clear` function look correct up there?

Comment: I added `@getServiceObject().serviceObject = null` to the clear function... same.

Comment: this is another question, but hint: its related to the clusterer saving markers

Comment: I see.  I've read every file, but I'm drawing a blank.  How do I talk with the clusterer?  Is it just `MarkerClusterer.clear()` or do I act on each marker within the cluster?  I tried the prior in the `objects/marker.coffee` file, and it cleared everything, but the markers that got added didn't show up until I changed zoom level.

Comment: Please ask a new question