# gmaps4rails V2 get markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, gmaps4rails

I'm storing the data like in [scope of markers variable for google maps (gmaps4rails gem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737094/scope-of-markers-variable-for-google-maps-gmaps4rails-gem/20376820#20376820)

```
Gmaps.store = {} #handler, markers

jQuery ->
Gmaps.store.handler = Gmaps.build 'Google'
Gmaps.store.handler.buildMap { internal: {id: 'map'} }, ->
Gmaps.store.markers = ....
```

How do I get the markers back? `Gmaps.store.markers` doesn't work.

Comment: what means `doesn't work.` ?

Comment: only the handler is stored in the hash as key: ![picture](http://i41.tinypic.com/29m3drb.png "picture")

Comment: I see markers below the handler in your screenshot

Comment: Right! And I can not retrive the content!

Comment: accessing an object property is basic javascript, what do you try?

Comment: Gmaps.store.handler works and Gmaps.store.markers returns undefined... I think it has to do with the assigning of markers inside the funktion. I really have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: your screenshots shows its an array. I suspect you try to get markers before they are created

Comment: Im trying to access it outside the Gmaps.store.handler.buildMap funktion... but you are right. Setting a timeout to retrive the markers did work! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve data in the callback to be sure they exist, adding a timer is very erratic.